# How to write excel file in csv comma delimited format using java in Apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, string, collections, apache-poi

i am trying to write a excel file in java using apache poi. i want to my excel file format in csv comma delimited. how can i do it ?
Here is my code which i am using it now -

```
public class ReadRfdsDump {

    public void readRfdsDump() 
    {
        try
        {

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\esatnir\\Videos\\sprint\\sprintvision.sprint.com_Trackor Browser_RF Design Sheet_07062018122740.xlsx"));

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();

            for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                Row row= sheet.getRow(i);
                System.out.println(df.formatCellValue(row.getCell(1)));
            }

            try {

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\CQ ADD\\Write CQ File\\"+s+".csv"));
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("Excel  has been written successfully on disk.");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i am using .csv to write excel file but i don't know if it is a correct format for csv(comma delimited) ?? or how can i write excel file in .csv(comma delimited) format ??

Answer (score 1):

Here you find your example to more details [click here](https://gist.github.com/robertchong/11071949)

```
private static final String CVS_SEPERATOR_CHAR=",";
        public static void csvToEXCEL(String csvFileName,String excelFileName) throws Exception{
            checkValidFile(csvFileName);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvFileName)));
            HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(new File(excelFileName) );
            HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.createSheet();
            String line= "";
            int rowNo=0;
            while ( (line=reader.readLine()) != null ){
                String[] columns = line.split(CVS_SEPERATOR_CHAR);// comma seperator
                 HSSFRow myRow =mySheet.createRow(rowNo);
                for (int i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
                    HSSFCell myCell = myRow.createCell(i);
                    myCell.setCellValue(columns[i]);
                }
                 rowNo++;
            }
            myWorkBook.write(writer);
            writer.close();
        }
    private static void checkValidFile(String fileName){
            boolean valid=true;
            try{
                File f = new File(fileName);
                if ( !f.exists() || f.isDirectory() ){
                    valid=false;
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                valid=false;
            }
            if ( !valid){
                System.out.println("File doesn't exist: " + fileName);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank for help but it is not working. it is showing error that file format has been corrupted. is there any other way by which i can do it ??